# Print row values from dataframe in vertical manner - R

Tags: r

I am pulling single row from a dataframe df.
I would like to print the values in vertical manner.

something like:

```
header_1    A
header_2    B
header_3    C
header_4    D
```

rather than

```
header_1  header_2  header_3  header_4
   A         B          C         D
```

Comment: `t`ranspose it (with the `t` function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you also need the columns names based on row names , here's how the whole code in addition to Rich's comment, should look like :

```
# create the dataset 

x=paste("Header_",1:4) 
y=c('A','B','C','D')
data=data.frame(x,y)

# transpose and rename columns 

data.T <- t(data[,2:ncol(data)]) # first transpose 
colnames(data.T) <- data[,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output by using the hidden drop = FALSE argument.

Using Prateek's data:

```
x=paste("Header_",1:4) 
y=c('A','B','C','D')
data=data.frame(x,y)
data
data[,1,drop =F]
          x
1 Header_ 1
2 Header_ 2
3 Header_ 3
4 Header_ 4
```